# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "arretieren" und "verhaften"?

Tags: meaning, austrian, archaism

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "arretieren" und "verhaften"?

Im unten angeführten *Verzeichnis politisch unverlässlicher Personen* (Dezember 1913, verm. von Österreich-Ungarn besetzter Teil der West-Ukraine, Quelle: [Thalerhof Concentration Camp Almanacs](https://www.elliotsbooks.com/?page=shop/flypage&product_id=103599)) kommen in der Spalte 9 (*Antrag was mit ihm im Alarm- bezw. Mobilisierungsfalle zu geschehen hätte*) folgende zwei Wörter vor:

1. **verhaften** (Zeilen 1, 4, 10, 12, 16, 17, 24, 26, 27, 5x, 56, 60)
2. **arretieren** (Zeilen 21, 23)

[image: Verzeichnis politisch unverlässlicher Personen]

Laut [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=arretieren+%2B+bedeutung) bedeutet *arretieren* "festnehmen, verhaften".

[image: Bedeutung von "arretieren" laut Google]

**Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "verhaften" und "arretieren"?** Warum hat der Verfasser dieser Liste zwei unterschiedliche Wörter verwendet, wo sie doch synonym erscheinen?

Comment: (My German is not good enough to express myself.) Legally, the difference in many languages is that "arrest" does not imply guilt (police does not need any evidence of criminal action to arrest anyone - only their own judgement), and "detention" does imply guilt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich habe leider keine historischen Belege für meine Antwort, kann deshalb nur aus meinem allgemeinen Sprachgefühl / meiner Erfahrung als Muttersprachler sprechen: Arretieren wird heute hauptsächlich in der Bedeutung „festsetzen“ verwendet.

Ich verstehe die Liste so, dass wenn jemand arretiert wird, dann wird er festgehalten um ihn dann ggf. einer Befragung zuzuführen. Ergibt die Befragung nähere Hinweise, dann kann aus der Arretierung eine Verhaftung werden.

Wird jemand „verhaftet“, dann wird er ohne weiteren Zwischenschritt direkt der Haft zugeführt, in Haft genommen.

Die Verhaftung ist also etwas unmittelbares, konkretes, während die Arretierung (erst mal) temporär zu sehen ist.

Auch heute noch unterscheidet man bei der Polizei die folgenden Begriffe:

**Arrestzelle**: zur vorübergehenden Unterbringung bis zu Feststellung des weiteren Verfahrens (das kann auch nur eine Personenfeststellung sein, wenn derjenige keinen Ausweis bei sich hat)

**Gefängniszelle**: Unterbringung nach einem Gerichtsurteil auf bestimmte, längere Zeit (bis auf Ausnahmefälle immer >1 Tag)